# Day-Time conventions spanning across years

Tags: daycounting

I have 2 dates, let's say 2010-01-01 and 2020-01-02, and I am interested in calculating the year fraction between them according to the Act/365 time convention.

Would this be just
$$
\frac{\text{raw # of days between the dates}}{365}
 = \frac{3653}{365}
 = 10 \tfrac{3}{365}
$$
or will I have to convert the years normally, and then only apply the convention to the segment which is under a year, resulting in
$$
10+\frac{\text{# of days between Jan 1st and Jan 2nd}}{365}
 = 10 \tfrac{1}{365}?
$$

---

Additionally, is it correct that if we use Act/Act it will be $10 \frac{1}{366}$ since 2020 is a leap year?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I found a couple of questions on day-count conventions, but did not see this asked explicitly.

Comment: PDF Page 14f: https://quant.opengamma.io/Interest-Rate-Instruments-and-Market-Conventions.pdf. It is defined as the day difference between d1 and d2 divided by 365 if it is Act/365 fixed.

Comment: Also asked Bloomberg, they are implementing direct difference as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kermittfrog has indicated in the comment, it's the former of your two versions, i.e. Date2 - Date1, divided by 365 (in your case 10.00822). Do note that you did not further specify, and we "assumed" it to be Act/365 *fixed*

(because there is also the Act/365 *Actual* convention, which accounts for leap years: 365 in all regular yrs, 366 in leap years --> the very same holds for act/act convention).